# How to copy zipped file data to one txt file

Tags: perl

Now i need to copy data inside the zip files to one .txt file i.e all R1 folder file data should copy and save in one R1.txt file similarly R2 folder file data should save in one single R2.txt file. is it possible to copy data from zipped files??

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy;
use strict;
use warnings;

print"Enter Folder name \n";
print"File name: ";
chomp(my $Filename=<>);

mkdir "R1";
mkdir "R2";


opendir(DIR,"$Filename") or die "cannot open directory";
foreach my $name (readdir(DIR))
{
next if ($name =~ /^\./);
  if($name =~ /R1/) { #compare $name not $Filename
   copy("$Filename/$name", "R1"); # copy the file from folder to R1 directory
   system("cat  $Filename\/$name >> R1.txt");
}
elsif($name =~ /R2/){
   copy("$Filename/$name","R2"); ## copy the file from folder to R2 directory
 system("cat  $Filename\/$name >> R2.txt");
    }
  }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to unzip them into a stream and save the stream as file.

Comment: without unzipping its not possible??

Comment: If you really want to merge two zip files into one, you need to concat this files into one file. Later when you need to unzip them, split them again.

Comment: that only i am asking , how to merge two zipped files??

Comment: The problem is not to merge two files... the real proble is split them latter. You can use "cat" to append file data, but you need to know where is the beginning of the next file to split them again. Then, try to insert a string with iteration number before next file.

Comment: no need of spliting sir, just i need to cat those files

Comment: But if you need to unzip later...

Comment: thats not my part of work, my work is to concatinate all zipped files thats it

Answer (score 0):

without unzipping the file you can extract the content, the simple and easiest way to do so without using modules is, to use unix command in perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $text = `unzip -c customer.xml.gz`;
print $text ."\n";
```

AFter extracting the contents, write the same into one.txt file